# button click is not workign

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the text by entering any id in the textbox like 0, 1 or 2. It's not showing when I press the button Get by Id.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name1" id="text1" value="" />
<input type="button" name="name2" id="btn1" value="Get by Id" />

<script>

 $("#btn1").click(function () {
        var id = $("#text1").val;
            $.getJSON("/api/Customer/" + id, function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: How specifically is this failing?  Are there any errors in your browser's development console?  When you use your browser's debugger, is the JavaScript code executed at all?  Is the click handler invoked?  Does `id` have the value you expect?  Is the AJAX call made?  What is the server's response?  Please provide information about the problem.  At least at a quick glance, you're not invoking the `val()` function properly.  It should be `$("#text1").val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the line below click, use this

```
var id = $("#text1").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$("#text1").val()` instead of `$("#text1").val;`

Your missing the function